# C# Text Representation of Method to Method Call

Tags: c#, string, methods, reflection

Suppose I have an instance of a class that contains several methods. I also have a textual representation of a function call for a method in that class. For example, the string might be `SomeMethod(5, "hello")`. I am looking to translate any given valid string into the appropriate method call.

So far I've been able to access the method by parsing the method name and then calling `GetType().GetMethod(method_name)` on the instance of the class. However, I am having difficulty with fulfilling the method signature. I can access the types of the method parameters using `MethodBase.GetParameters()`, but I would have to know the types to cast at compile time to make the function call valid.

I also have the feeling that my entire approach may be wrong. Is there a common pattern for accomplishing this?

Comment: Can you give a minimal working test case?

Comment: Have you looked at using the Roslyn scripting API? https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

Comment: I am using Unity and I do not believe that is supported.